# JavaScript/PHP Popup when Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
    var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload';

    myEvent(chkevent, function(e) {
        var confirmationMessage = 'HELLO';
        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
        return confirmationMessage;
    });
</script>
```

Which runs a small pop up box when the user trys to refresh the page the script is running on.

However, how can I prevent it from running the pop up if they click the Submit button?

Comment: Does the submit button currently run any other javascript?

Comment: No it doesn't. It is simply an <input type="submit"> button in a form with <form action="member-payment-code.php" method="post">.

Comment: Would it also be possible to stop the box showing if they LEAVE the page i.e. click another link in the navigation bar? I only want it showing for page refreshes to be honest.

Comment: Yes - both of these are possible, but it involves attaching click handlers to everything.  You'd set a flag that the function in your question checks to see whether or not it should display the message.  That said, you can't stop someone from refreshing the page anyway if they want to - what is your end goal here, perhaps you should just gracefully handle the refresh?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Note that you have to refresh the snippet for your message to appear, but not when you click the button.

```js
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload';
var unloading = true;

myEvent(chkevent, function(e) {
  if(!unloading) return;
  var confirmationMessage = 'HELLO';
  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
  return confirmationMessage;
});

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  unloading = false;
  // Because this button does nothing, the reload will load an empty page in SO
  // However, note there is no beforeunload event actioned.
  location.reload();
});

document.write('Current Time: ' + Date.now())
```

```html
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" />
```

Comment: I have <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-warning"> as my input button and the Javascript code you provided me. It works when you refresh the oage (i.e. the message about refreshing pops up) but it also appears when you click Submit? I want the Submit button to just run the form action="" code correctly.

Comment: Don't forget I added a variable that needs to be changed on submit. It might be better to actually use `yourForm.addEventListener(''submit', ...)` instead of a click on the button. Also note that there is an extra line inside the `beforeunload` event function. Otherwise I would say that my snippet here works, so I cannot really say why it isn't working on your end.